# How to make customized Material Toggle Button?

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-togglebutton

I want to customized Material Toggle Button like the following. I have tried but not succeed to achieve this output. following is xml code I tried but not desired output. I go through the [Offical Documents](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button) but no help about this. Please help me if anyone knows about this
Thanks

[image: Desired Output]

**xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
                    android:id="@+id/outdoor_toggle_buttonGroup"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:singleSelection="true"
                    app:checkedButton="@+id/btn_walking"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_walking"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/walking"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
                        app:shapeAppearance="@style/CustomShapeAppearance"
                        />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_running"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/running"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
                        app:shapeAppearance="@style/CustomShapeAppearance"
                        />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_cycling"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cycling"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
                        app:shapeAppearance="@style/CustomShapeAppearance"
                        />


                </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

**Style**

```
 <style name="CustomShapeAppearance">
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">20dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">20dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">20dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">20dp</item>
    </style>
```

**output**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using a `TabLayout` inside a `MaterialCardView`. The `MaterialCardView` is needed to draw the corner radius of the outer section and the `TabLayout` to draw each Tab. The `TabLayout` has a property `app:tabBackground` which can be used to set a Drawable selector for the Tab Selected/Unselected state.

**Xml layout:**

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:strokeWidth="0dp"
    app:strokeColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tabs_selector"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabTextAppearance">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Walking" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Running" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cycling" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

where `@drawable/tabs_selector` is the Tab Drawable Selector to set the Selected/Unselected state like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected" />
</selector>
```

For `@drawable/tab_bg_selected` Selected state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#31d480" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

For `@drawable/tab_bg_unselected` Unselected State:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

and `@style/CustomTabTextAppearance` is a custom Tab TextAppearance in case you want to change for each Tab the Text Size or Font Family like below:

```
<style name="CustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_mono</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_mono</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

**Result:**

[image: Tab1_Selected]

[image: Tab2_Selected]

[image: Tab3_Selected]